# Утрата const квалификаторов в параметрах прототипов функций и методов

Tags: c++, c, const

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
void func(const void*const data, const uint32_t size);
```

Я никак не могу понять, почему это объявление функции преобразуется к виду:

```
void func(const void* data, uint32_t size);
```

То, что такое преобразование происходит, становится понятно при всплывающих подсказках в популярных `IDE`, например - в `Visual Studio`.

Кроме того, компиляторы без вопросов принимают такой код:

```
void func(const void*data, uint32_t size);

void func(const void*const data, const uint32_t size)
{
}
```

Кроме того, квалификаторы теряются не только в прототипах функций, но и в прототипах методов.

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему это происходит? Что на этот счет говорят стандарты `C` и `C++`?

Comment: Для вызывающего кода `const` все равно ничего не меняет, так что смысл в этом есть. Например в хедере можно `const` не писать, чтобы не отвлекал, а в реализации поставить его там, где он нужен.

Comment: Для пользовательского типа `const` из прототипа функции/метода тоже отбрасывается (если верить `Visual Studio`).

Comment: Аргументы в функции принимаются как копии. Смысл константности имеет только внутри реализации самой функции. По-этому в предварительном объявлении функции эти параметры для аргументов просто игнорируются.

Answer (score 3):

Нашёл в стандарте мельком в примечаниях, что **const** взаимозаменяем, т.е. это один и тот-же тип.
Как аргумент, возвращаемое значение и элементы объединения **union**.

> **6.2.5 Types**
>   Any type so far mentioned is an unqualified type. Each unqualified type has several qualified versions of its type, 47)
>   corresponding to the combinations of one, two, or all three of the
>   **const**, **volatile**, and **restrict** qualifiers. The qualified or unqualified
>   versions of a type are distinct types that belong to the same type
>   category and have the same representation and alignment requirements. 48) A derived type is not qualified by the qualifiers (if any) of the
>   type from which it is derived.
>   
>   47) See 6.7.3 regarding qualified array and function types.
>   48) The
>   same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply
>   interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from
>   functions, and members of unions.

перевод :

> **6.2.5 Типы**
>   Любой тип, упомянутый до сих пор, является неквалифицированным типом. Каждый неквалифицированный тип имеет
>   несколько квалифицированных версий своего типа, 47), соответствующих
>   комбинациям одного, двух или всех трех квалификаторов **const**, **volatile**
>   и **restrict**. Квалифицированные или неквалифицированные версии типа -
>   это отдельные типы, которые принадлежат к одной и той же категории
>   типов и имеют одинаковые требования к представлению и выравниванию. 48) Производный тип не квалифицирован квалификаторами (если таковые
>   имеются) типа, из которого он получен.
>   
>   47) См. 6.7.3 относительно
>   квалифицированных массивов и типов функций.
>   48) Те же требования к
>   представлению и выравниванию подразумевают взаимозаменяемость в
>   качестве аргументов функций, возвращаемых значений из функций и членов
>   объединений.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Эта информация проясняет не все.

Comment: Тип `int` и `int const` - один и тот-же. Проверьте с помощью `std::cout<<typeid(int const).name();` Добавление константности не меняет ничего. А компилятор выбирает функции по типу аргументов.

Comment: В комментариях выше вроде-бы разжевали. Константность имеет область видимости **внутри** работы функции, а не снаружи. А предварительное объявление функции должно показать только тип элементов, а не как вы будете потом с ним потом возиться.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что при выводе типа функции cv-квалификаторы *верхнего* уровня, модифицирующие типы параметров функции, удаляются. Иными словами, две функции

```
int f1(int);
int f2(const int);
```

имеют одинаковый функциональный тип.

Процесс "упрощения" параметров функции при выводе типа функции описан в *n4659 [dcl.fct] 11.3.5/5*:

> [...] After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of **T**” or of function type **T** is adjusted to be “pointer to **T**”. After producing the list of parameter types, any top-level *cv-qualifiers* modifying a parameter type are deleted when forming the function type. [...]
>
> [...] После определения типа каждого параметра, любой параметр типа "массив элементов типа **T**" или функционального типа **T** корректируется в тип "указатель на **T**". После формирования списка типов параметров, любые *cv-квалификаторы* верхнего уровня, модифицирующие типы параметров, **удаляются** при формировании функционального типа. [...]

Взгляните, например, на [следующий код](https://ideone.com/nivaPJ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int (*a1)(int) = nullptr;
    int (*a2)(const int) = nullptr;
    int (* const a3)(int) = nullptr;
    cout << is_same<decltype(a1), decltype(a2)>::value << " " 
         << is_same<decltype(a1), decltype(a3)>::value << endl; //1 0

    int (*b1)(int *) = nullptr;
    int (*b2)(int [100]) = nullptr;
    const int (*b3)(int *) = nullptr;
    cout << is_same<decltype(b1), decltype(b2)>::value << " " 
         << is_same<decltype(b1), decltype(b3)>::value << endl; //1 0

    int (*c1)(int, long(char, int [5][10])) = nullptr;
    int (*c2)(const int, long(const char, int (*)[10])) = nullptr;
    int (* const c3)(int, long(char, int [5][10])) = nullptr;
    cout << is_same<decltype(c1), decltype(c2)>::value << " " 
         << is_same<decltype(c1), decltype(c3)>::value << endl; //1 0
}
```

Дополнительные подробности и примеры можно найти в *n4659 [over.load] 16.1/3*:

> As specified in 11.3.5, function declarations that have equivalent parameter declarations declare the same function and therefore cannot be overloaded:
>
> Как указано в 11.3.5, объявления функций, имеющих одинаковые объявления параметров, объявляют одну и ту же функцию, и не могут быть перегружены:

*(3.2)*:

> Parameter declarations that differ only in a pointer * versus an array [] are equivalent. That is, the array declaration is adjusted to become a pointer declaration (11.3.5). Only the second and subsequent array dimensions are significant in parameter types (11.3.4).
>
> Объявления параметров, отличающиеся только тем, что в одном тип задаётся как указатель *, а в другом как массив [], являются эквивалентными. То есть, объявление массива корректируется, чтобы стать объявлением указателя (11.3.5). Только второе и последующие измерения массива имеют значения в типах параметров (11.3.4).

Пример:

```
int f(char*);
int f(char[]); // Эквивалентно f(char*);
int f(char[7]); // Эквивалентно f(char*);
int f(char[9]); // Эквивалентно f(char*);

int g(char(*)[10]);
int g(char[5][10]); // Эквивалентно g(char(*)[10]);
int g(char[7][10]); // Эквивалентно g(char(*)[10]);
int g(char(*)[20]); // Отличается от g(char(*)[10]);
```

*(3.3)*:

> Parameter declarations that differ only in that one is a function type and the other is a pointer to the same function type are equivalent. That is, the function type is adjusted to become a pointer to function type (11.3.5).
>
> Объявления параметров, которые отличаются только тем, что в одном тип задаётся как функциональный тип, а в другом как указатель на тот же функциональный тип, являются эквивалентными. То есть, функциональный тип корректируется, чтобы стать указателем на функциональный тип (11.3.5).

Пример:

```
void h(int());
void h(int (*)()); // Повторное объявление h(int())
void h(int x()) { } // Определение h(int())
void h(int (*x)()) { } // ill-formed: повторное определение h(int())
```

*(3.4)*:

> Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence of **const** and/or **volatile** are equivalent. That is, the **const** and **volatile** type-specifiers for each parameter type are ignored when determining which function is being declared, defined, or called.
>
> Only the **const** and **volatile** type-specifiers at the outermost level of the parameter type specification are ignored in this fashion; **const** and **volatile** type-specifiers buried within a parameter type specification are significant and can be used to distinguish overloaded function declarations. 123) In particular, for any type **T**, “pointer to **T**”, “pointer to **const T**”, and “pointer to **volatile T**” are considered distinct parameter types, as are “reference to **T**”, “reference to **const T**”, and “reference to **volatile T**”.
>
> 123) When a parameter type includes a function type, such as in the case of a parameter type that is a pointer to function, the **const** and **volatile** type-specifiers at the outermost level of the parameter type specifications for the inner function type are also ignored.
>
> Объявления параметров, которые отличаются только наличием или отсутствием **const** и/или **volatile**, являются эквивалентными. То есть, спецификаторы типа **const** и **volatile** для каждого типа параметра игнорируются при определении того, какая функция объявлена, определена или вызвана.
>
> Только спецификаторы типа **const** и **volatile** на самом внешнем уровне спецификации типа параметра игнорируются подобным образом; спецификаторы типа **const** и **volatile** "на вложенных уровнях" спецификации типа параметра не игнорируются и могут быть использованы для объявления перегруженных функций. 123) В частности, для любого типа **T**, "указатель на **T**", "указатель на **const T**" и "указатель на **volatile T**" считаются различными типами параметров, так же как и "ссылка на **T**", "ссылка на **const T**", и "ссылка на **volatile T**".
>
> 123) Когда тип параметра включает функциональный тип, например, в случае типа параметра, являющегося указателем на функцию, то спецификаторы типа **const** и **volatile**  на самом внешнем уровне спецификации типа параметра вложенного функционального типа также игнорируются.

Пример:

```
typedef const int cInt;
int f (int);
int f (const int); // Повторное объявление f(int)
int f (int) { /* ... */ } // Определение f(int)
int f (cInt) { /* ... */ } // Ошибка: повторное определение f(int)
```